# thicker lines for sm.density.compare

Tags: r

I am using something along those lines:

```
library(sm)

sm.density.compare(X, Class)
```

Is there a way to increase the thickness of the density plot lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen this particular package before, but if you investigate how the `sm::sm.density.compare` function is structured, it receives its graphical parameters from `sm:::.sm.Options`, where line width `lwd` is set to 1.

Hence you simply need to pass the `lwd` option to the function as you would usually do with base plots. See following:

```
y <- rnorm(100)
g <- rep(1:2, rep(50,2))
sm.density.compare(y, g, model="equal")
sm.density.compare(y, g, model="equal", lwd = 3)
```

Let me know if this does not work or this isn't what you had in mind.

Comment: How did you find lwd as an option? I can't see it referenced in: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sm/sm.pdf